# how to debug a crash in an optimized program

Tags: debugging, gcc, optimization

I'm trying to debug a crash appening only on some cpu and only when compiled with gcc optmiziation on (-03), it doesn't happen with -O0. both compile are with -g

I embedded dr. mingw in the application because the crash is happening on a pc the is not mine.
I got the following crash report:

```
Error occured on Thursday, August 14, 2014 at 12:07:08.



C:\Users\Schüle\Arena\Engines\Vajolet\vajolettestc\vajolet2c.exe caused an Access Violation at location 0040C826 in module C:\Users\Schüle\Arena\Engines\Vajolet\vajolettestc\vajolet2c.exe Writing to location 023C8000.



Registers:

eax=000036b3 ebx=0299d130 ecx=00df885d edx=023ba528 esi=be220226 edi=023b9178

eip=0040c826 esp=0299cf30 ebp=0299fe78 iopl=0         nv up ei ng nz ac po cy

cs=0023  ss=002b  ds=002b  es=002b  fs=0053  gs=002b             efl=00010297



AddrPC   Params

0040C826 0299FEC0 00DFAFE0 00DFAFE0  vajolet2c.exe-------------------



Error occured on Thursday, August 14, 2014 at 13:24:32.



C:\Users\Schüle\Arena\Engines\Vajolet\vajolettestc\vajolet2c.exe caused an Access Violation at location 0040C826 in module C:\Users\Schüle\Arena\Engines\Vajolet\vajolettestc\vajolet2c.exe Writing to location 00C68000.



Registers:

eax=00002dad ebx=02bfd130 ecx=00b5887d edx=00c5c940 esi=bfffffff edi=00c5b8d8

eip=0040c826 esp=02bfcf30 ebp=02bffe78 iopl=0         nv up ei ng nz na po cy

cs=0023  ss=002b  ds=002b  es=002b  fs=0053  gs=002b             efl=00010287



AddrPC   Params

0040C826 02BFFEC0 00B5AFE0 00B5AFE0  vajolet2c.exe
```

both times the program crashed with Program Counter at address 0x0040C826 if I am not wrong.

I created a map of my file linking the program with the linker option "-Wl,-Map,prog.map" a

inside the map file i found this line :

```
.....
.text    0x0040a130   0x48f0 search.o
         0x0040a140        search::printPV(
         0x0040a720        search::printAllPV(
         0x0040bac0        search::StartThinking(
.text    0x0040ea20  0x8940 position.0
.....
```

so I think the problem is inside the StartThinking Function.

How can I get some more information from gcc? Can I create a disassembly mixed with code?

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

after searching on internet I found that I can create an asm  file with asm mixed to c code with the option -Wa,-adhln.

after that I calculated the offset to search in the asm file by doing 0x0040c826-0x0040a130 and I found the wrong instruction.

the sam file pointed me to the wrong c++ line!!